# How to send “ctrl + c” in MobaXterm

Tags: mobaxterm

In [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net), any time you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, it opens the “find in terminal” dialog, preventing you from using hotkeys like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

How do you work around this?

Comment: Same problem here - and Alt seems to close the application now! It's not down to remapping via keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Copy: select your text using mouse

Paste: Shift + insert

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser!  Would you be able to improve your answer by going more in-depth with your solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should note that I originally intended "control + c" to mean "cancel" as is standard in many terminal applications, however I agree that your answer may be useful to some people who may find this via google

Answer (score 2):

Find in terminal is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> by default. You must have remapped your keys.

If you go to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts in Mobaxterm you can remap your "Find in Terminal" back to the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue, pressing CTRL alone resulted in same action as CTRL-TAB, even though keyboard map had not been changed & this action was still correctly mapped as CTRL-TAB.

Cleared by pressing CTRL & TAB several times, thereafter it did not respond to CTRL on its own, and allowed use of CTRL-C again.